# failed to set the attribute in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app, frontend using HTML5, backend using Django.

I the JavaScript part I dynamically create the table header based on user selection in the previous page. But when I tried to set the data-field attribute to load the data dynamically, it could not work. although there's no error in F12 dev tool, the data could not shown in the table (I checked in dev tool, the data-field is there but no data shown in frontend. The first fixed one , course dose  shown）.

```
      <table id="thisTable"  contenteditable='true' class="table table-bordered table-sm" width="100%" cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"
                   id="bk-table"
                   data-toggle="table"
                   data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                   data-cookie="true"
                   data-cookie-id-table="materialId"
                   data-show-columns="true"
                   data-show-refresh="true"
                   data-show-fullscreen="true"
                   data-show-export="true"
                   data-height="650"
                    {#                   data-sticky-header="true"#}
                    {#                   data-sticky-header-offset-left="7em"#}
                    {#                   data-sticky-header-offset-right="7em"#}
                   data-click-to-select="true"
                   data-id-field="id"
                   data-show-footer="true"
                   data-url="/api/materials/"
                   data-query-params="queryParams"
                   data-remember-order="true"
                   data-pagination="true"
                   data-side-pagination="server"
                   data-total-field="count"
                   data-data-field="results">
                <thead class="thead-dark" >
                <tr contenteditable='true'>
                    <!--th  data-sortable="true" >ID</th-->
                    <th data-field="courseCode" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="renderCourse"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

            </table>



   <script>
const eText_iBookStore  = ['Course Code', 'Course Material Title', 'eISBN/VBID', 'iSBN']
              function queryParams(params) {
                    params['limit'] = localStorage['Format'];
                    params['discipline'] = localStorage['discipline'];
                    params['Add_Information'] = localStorage['Add_Information'];
                    if (params['Add_Information'] == "eText_iBookStore")
                    {
                        //document.getElementsByTagName("th")[0].setAttribute("data-field", "id");
                        //document.getElementsByTagName("th")[1].setAttribute("data-field", "courseCode");
        
                        //document.getElementsByTagName("th")[3].setAttribute("data-field", "book.isbn");
                        for (i=0;i<eText_iBookStore.length;i++)
                        {
                            var tr = document.getElementById('thisTable').tHead.children[0],
                                th = document.createElement('th');
                            tr.appendChild(th);
                        }
        
        
                        $( "table thead tr th" ).each(function( index ) {
        
                            $( this ).text(eText_iBookStore[index]);
                            console.log(eText_iBookStore[index]);
                            console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
                        });
        
                        document.getElementsByTagName("th")[2].setAttribute("data-field", "book.title");
        } }</script>
```

[image]

[image]

The data-field attribute dynamically loaded in js does not work like that added in HTML, (the former could not load data )

Comment: Why do you go back and forth between jQuery and vanilla JS?

Comment: Are you sure the `data-field` attribute isn't being set? If you inspect the element in DevTools, you don't see it?

Comment: Why do you go back and forth between jQuery and vanilla JS---I just paste some code from web, not sure if 's   vanilla JS or jQuery

Comment: `Unexpected end of input` you aren't closed your function brackets also where's `eText_iBookStore` array that you get it's length ?

Comment: I think that you also needs to provide example of your `params` object

Comment: Are you adding the data field before or after you initialize the datatable plugin?

Comment: @Barmar  adding the data field after init

Comment: @Barmar  the data field on HTML works well, but it could not work for the one after adding dynamically using js

Comment: Sounds like the datatable plugin doesn't detect attribute changes automatically. You'll need to check its documentation to see how to make it detect this.

Answer (score 0):

- the code is working well and adding the attribute but you are creating unnecessary loop inside the loop of `eText_iBookStore` so i remove `.each` loop and added the array element directly
- because i haven't something like your code inside my `localStorage` i just set a value to them and created the `eText_iBookStore`  array

```
function queryParams(params) {
      params['limit'] = "data"
      params['discipline'] = "data"
      params['Add_Information'] = "eText_iBookStore"
      var eText_iBookStore = [1,2,3,4]

      if (params['Add_Information'] == "eText_iBookStore") {
          for (var i = 0;i < eText_iBookStore.length; i++) {
              var tr = document.getElementById('thisTable').tHead.children[0],
              th = document.createElement('th');
              th.innerText = eText_iBookStore[i];
              tr.appendChild(th);
          }
         document.getElementsByTagName("th")[2].setAttribute("data-field", "book.title");
    }
    
}
queryParams({})
```

[image]

Comment: What did you change to make it it work? If you didn't change anything, then this shouldn't be an answer.

Comment: If you think that this isn't answer then i also think that this question should closed because the code is working well

Comment: anyway i edited it and added a short code in vanillajs

Comment: not the attribute problem, it's this problem: if attribute was added dynamically in javascript after table init, it could not show the data